# Javascript animation: stop doing multiple jumps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made this character moving with javascript.

Everything is working fine, by binding keycodes to this character i got smooth animation.
I tried binding jump with `spaceBar` .

**Problem**-

My character is jumping nicely but multiple times.I tried adding `event.preventDefault()`
But that didn't do trick.

I want a smooth jump only for once i press spaceBar.

Here is code for jump-

```
if(spaceBar)
    {
        box.animate({top:"-50"},100)
        .animate({top:"50"},100);
        event.isDefaultPrevented();
    }
```

And fiddle-

[Moving character](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/ruuhK/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the animation to go back down (Fall to the ground, i guess you could call it) into the previous animation's completion parameter:

```
if(spaceBar)
{
    box.animate({top:"-50"},100,function(){
        box.animate({top:"50"},100);
    })
    event.isDefaultPrevented();
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruuhK/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use jQuery's `.clearQueue()` function (http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)

```
if(spaceBar)
{
    box.clearQueue().animate({top:"-50"},100).animate({top:"50"},100);
}
```

For your refence: http://jsfiddle.net/FGPCC/

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for me:

```
if(spaceBar)
{
    box.clearQueue().animate({top:"-=50"},100).animate({top:"+=50"},100);
}
```